# If $ f(x.y) = f(x) + f(y) + (x+y-1)/xy $ then what is f(x)?

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus, functions, exponential-function

$$ f(x.y) = f(x) + f(y) + (x+y-1)/xy $$ 
And it is given that 
$$ f'(1) = 2 $$ 
And we have to find 
$$ \lfloor f(e^{100})\rfloor $$
I tried to guess the function by some observation and deduces it to be as $$ f(x) = -1/x$$ but the thing is that it doesnt satisfy the second condition of the question .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because of the product to sum property, you'll need a $\ln x$ in there.  And since $$\frac{x+y-1}{xy} = \frac{1}{x}+\frac{1}{y} -\frac{1}{xy}$$  you'll probably want a $1/x$.  And that seems to be enough.  Let $f(x) = \ln x -1/x$.
In fact, for any constant $a$, $f(x) = a\ln x - 1/x$ would solve the equation, and then you can adjust the $a$ to satisfy the derivative requirement.  (Your solution uses $a=0$.)